# AIC criterion on a felm regression model

Tags: r

I have a regression model which was computed using the felm package.
Hence i have a "large felm" object in the environment

I want to compute the AIC criterion on it, how can i ?

i tried using this function which doesn't appear to work, it returns a "numeric(empty)" result

```
AIC_adj <- function(mod){
  # Number of observations
  n.N   <- nrow(mod$model)
  # Residuals vector
  u.hat <- residuals(mod)
  # Variance estimation
  s.sq  <- log( (sum(u.hat^2)/(n.N)))
  # Number of parameters (incl. constant) + one additional for variance estimation
  p     <-  length(coef(mod)) + 1
  
  # Note: minus sign cancels in log likelihood
  aic <- 2*p  +  n.N * (  log(2*pi) + s.sq  + 1 ) 
  
  return(aic)
}
```

the model is given by

```
        G         D1         D2         D4         D5         D6   posratio     sd_ret       G:D1 
 0.0832205 -0.0030118 -0.0006392  0.0007287  0.0004233 -0.0013440  0.0059718  0.2344416  0.0087144 
      G:D2       G:D4       G:D5       G:D6 G:posratio   G:sd_ret 
 0.0046054 -0.0028214 -0.0033844 -0.0076368 -0.0881973  0.6204865
```

Comment: I think you should ask this question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: just change in the first line in `AIC_adj function` from  `n.N   <- nrow(mod$model)` to `n.N   <- mod$N`.